# Multiple Parallel Threads In Custom Control

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am inside wpf and I have a custom control

```
public class MyListControl : ListBox
{
   ...
```

Now I would like to run through `Items` but using 4 different threads. One thread should take first part of the list, second thread should apply computations on second part and so on...

Take a look at this pseudo code:

```
var originalSource = this.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().ToList();
int part = originalSource.Count / 4;

Task.Factory.StartNew(..
    DoSomething(originalSource.Take(part));

Task.Factory.StartNew(..
    DoSomething(originalSource.Skipt(part).Take(part), ...);

Task.Factory.StartNew(..
    DoSomething(originalSource.Skip(part * 2).Take(part), ... );

Task.Factory.StartNew(..
    DoSomething(originalSource.Skip(part * 3).Take(part), ...); ...
```

To sum up the list gets divided in 4 pieces and 4 different threads shall speed up the computations.

Now the question is how do I do this?

I cannot do this in ViewModel, it has to be inside the custom control!

Task.Factory.StartNew seems to be wrong tool for this since I get exceptions like:

A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll

What do you guys suggest me to do?

I tried Dispatcher.BeginInvoke but they are being invoked one after another and not parallel.

I need a parallel solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using Background Worker? See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the WaitAll to wait for the threads to finish and pass batches from the lists?

```
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff(list1));
Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff(list2)); 
Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
```

Comment: Like I said in my question the Tasks are not working for me... A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll. It seems that StartNew(..) is not working when in ui thread

Answer (score -1):

Since you might be performing a computationally intensive task, consider using a [Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx) instead of normal threads/tasks. This will put your `DoSomething()` on a back ground thread.

Comment: I tried that too but I always get this exception A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll

Comment: Can you show us the line on which that exception is thrown?